# Double connection ethernet + ppp

Tags: linux, connection, ip, iptables, ppp

Sorry if the question is trivial, but I can't figure out..

I've my ethernet connection and I've created a ppp connection.

Now, keeping alive eth0 connection, how can I test ppp connection?

I would like to do something like this:

```
 ping <any_ip> -<ppp0 connection>
```

is this possibile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either make the `ppp` link your default route,

```
route add default dev ppp0
```

or just add that route for the single IP you wish to ping,

```
route add <any_ip> dev ppp0
```

Comment: so, with the second, each time I ping that ip, ping always use ppp0 connetion?

Comment: @Velthune Each time you do anything with that ip. ping, telnet, ftp, ssh, http, etc. Unless you remove the route.

Comment: thanks, now I'm testing